# How do I change the packaging format in Gradle similar to Maven's <packaging> tag?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jar, build.gradle

In another Maven project, I was able to export my project into a KJar format using the following tag:

< packaging >kjar < / packaging >

However, my current project needs to be done in Gradle. I've tried different things within the build.gradle file, but I couldn't find a direct alternative to Maven's < packaging > tag.

Is there any way I can make the Gradle project use 'KJar' as its packaging?

Comment: There does not need to be a Kie Gradle plugin analogous to the Maven one - which provides the packaging; so you cannot generate a KJar from Graldle automatically. That does not mean you cannot generate it manually - it just seems to require a few extra files to be generated - https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/03/14/what-is-a-kjar. I don’t know if this is helpful - https://github.com/Spantree/drools-examples

Comment: Thanks man, maybe it's really impossible to force it via Gradle. Maybe I should just use Maven